# Cannot connet to OpenVPN client

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am using an OpenVPN Portable and when i try to connect to a client  the following error appears:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:16: register-dns (2.1.1)
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.10.240
CreateFile failed on TAP device: \\.\Global\{005FCE57-4C2B-4407-B5E4-8262E2C8BD78}.tap
All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use.
Exiting
```

To solve this issue I installed the TAP-Windows but nothing changed...

My computer is running on windows 7.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the computer?

Comment: Yes, i am an administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by acessing the Device Manager on windows, after I had installed the drivers of the vpn and then update TAP-windows adapter.